# What is the name of this type of palindromic number?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, recreational-mathematics, palindrome

A palindromic number is one that reads the same forwards as backwards, an example of which is $17071$.

In the UK yesterday's date was $16/3/16$, the convention being day/month/year.
Clearly $16316$ is not palindromic in the usual sense.  However if you swap the day with the year it still is $16316$.  This a kind of 'block' palindrome whereby you can swap number blocks.  Another example is $26726$ here you can swap the $26$ around.

**Is there a name for such 'palindromic' numbers?**

I had a look on the internet but didn't find anything obvious as the problem seems linked to which base the number is written in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, every number is "block palindromic" with a single block. Whether you exclude this case or not, to my knowledge there is no such term.

Comment: I don't think I've seen a standardi(s/z)ed term for this. Probably "non-trivially block palindromic" is a reasonable name.

Comment: @Travis and Giovanni Resta Ok thanks. I like the idea of non trivial as it includes the unavoidable case that a number is bock palindromic using itself as a block.  Hmm I wonder if there is a counting method to see how many 'different' ways a number can be block palindromic.  $242472424$  can choose the blocks $24$ or $2424$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of $2018$ there is a name that was used in a paper, "Block palindromes", in "*Block Palindromes: A New Generalization of Palindrome, Keisuke Goto.*"

- Links: [Arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.00198) / [Springer.com](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-00479-8_15) / [Researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325543823_Block_Palindromes_A_New_Generalization_of_Palindromes).

Where they use the following definition:

> A block palindrome is a string that becomes a palindrome when identical substrings are replaced with a distinct character.

In the paper, they give an example of "block factorization": `To|kyo|_|and|_|Kyo|to` (page 2).

For example, your $16316$ is a block palindrome with blocks ("block factorization"): $16|3|16$.

Comment: Thanks I'd completely forgotten about this idea. I should have studied it further!